# How can I solve SICP 2.4 in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, sicp

This exercise ask for implement `cons`, `car` and `cdr` functions using only lambda functions.

The function `cons(a,b)` create a list of `a` followed by `b`, `car(l)` returns the first element of list `l`, and `cdr(l)` returns the rest of the list.

I got it working with lists of only two elements, but when you try to cons more elements it fails. Any Ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename A>
A car( std::function< A(std::function<A(A,A)>) > m ){
    return m( [](A a, A){ return a; } );
}

template<typename A>
A cdr( std::function< A(std::function<A(A,A)>) > m ){
    return m( [](A, A b){ return b; } );
}

template<typename A>
std::function< A(std::function<A(A,A)>) >
cons( const A a, const A b){
    return [=](std::function<A(A,A)> l){ return l(a,b); };
}

int main(){
    //auto l = cons( cons( 1, 2 ), 3 );  // no matching function
    auto l = cons( 1, 2 );

    std::cout << car( l ) << ", " << cdr( l ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I notice that the real signature of cons should be:

```
template<typename A,typename B, typename C>
std::function< C(std::function<C(A,B)>) >
cons( const A a, const B b){
    return [=](std::function<C(A,B)> l){ return l(a,b); };
}
```

Because this version also didn't work.

**UPDATE 2**
It can be simplified (more readable) with:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
using Cell<A,B,C> = std::function<C(A,B)>
```

Comment: Since you are asking almost specifically for the case that fails, you should be asking the question on StackOverflow, Not here :)

Comment: I didn't ask on stackoverflow because this is a "mental exercise"

Comment: Morween, maybe you are right, its posible to move the question to stackoverflow or I should create again there.

Comment: @Zhen it Is possible to have the question moved. You might want to contact our Community Mod Jamal, he will probably look at this when he comes back.

Comment: He could always re-edit (or repost if there is a migration) once the code is working if he want a real review of his code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cons` from your example could not be compiled, because compiler is unable to deduce return type for lambda function. What you are looking for specifically is polymorphic lambda function. Unfortunately C++11 doesn't support polymorphic lambdas, but there are several ways to implement `cons`, `car` and `cdr` in C++ anyway.

The first (and possibly the most straightforward) way to implement `cons`, `car` and `cdr` is using `std::tuple` or `std::pair`. This implementation is almost similar to definitions in [chapter 2.1.3 of the book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%_sec_2.1.3).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename A, typename B>
A car( std::tuple<A, B> m ) {
    return std::get<0>(m);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
B car( std::tuple<A, B> m ) {
    return std::get<1>(m);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
std::tuple<A, B>
cons(const A a, const B b) {
    return std::tuple<A, B>(a, b);
}

int main() {
    auto l = cons(cons(1, 2), 3);
    std::cout << car(car(l)) << ", " << cdr(car(l)) << ", ";
    std::cout << cdr(l) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But this implementation is not following original idea of [exercise 2.4](https://github.com/satori/edu/blob/master/sicp/2.1/2.04.scm). To follow it we could simply create our own `pair` class and implement `operator()` method parametrized by lambda return type.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename A, typename B>
class pair {
    A _a;
    B _b;

public:
    pair(const A a, const B b): _a(a), _b(b) {}

    template<typename R>
    R operator()(std::function<R(A, B)> func) {
        return func(_a, _b);
    }
};
```

And then we could implement `cons`, `car` and `cdr` just using it:

```cpp
template<typename A, typename B>
A car(pair<A, B> p) {
    return p( std::function<A(A, B)> ( [](A a, B) { return a; } ) );
}

template<typename A, typename B>
B cdr(pair<A, B> p) {
    return p( std::function<B(A, B)> ( [](A, B b) { return b; } ) );
}

template<typename A, typename B>
pair<A, B>
cons(const A a, const B b) {
    return pair<A, B>(a, b);
}

int main() {
    auto p = cons(cons("a", 2), 3);
    std::cout << car(car(p)) << ", " << cdr(car(p)) << ", ";
    std::cout << cdr(p) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand, C++14 (provisionally named C++1y) will introduce some features like generic lambdas which might simplify implementation.

**UPDATE**

After reading [proposal for generic (polymorphic) lambda expressions](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3559.pdf) in C++14, I've come to the following working implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

auto car = [](auto func) { return func( [](auto a, auto b) { return a; } ); };
auto cdr = [](auto func) { return func( [](auto a, auto b) { return b; } ); };
auto cons = [](auto a, auto b) { return [=](auto func) { return func(a, b); }; };

int main() {
    auto p = cons( cons("a", 2), 3 );
    std::cout << car(car(p)) << ", " << cdr(car(p)) << ", ";
    std::cout << cdr(p) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please note, that it will only work with compiler implementing such proposal (e.g. GCC 4.8, Clang 3.4) using `-std=c++1y` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But your implementation of `cons` breaks the rule of "use only lambda functions". Maybe isn't posible to have it done on C++11

Comment: You should note that lambda functions in C++11 are similar to anonymous structure with defined `operator()` method. The problem is in missing polymorphic lambda functions in C++11, but as I have mentioned previously, C++14 will introduce [generic lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3559.pdf) which might help.

Comment: Great, the C++14 implementation nails it